# Save IPython notebook directly to RST format?

Tags: python, ipython, restructuredtext

Is there a built-in or convenience function or save option to directly save an IPython notebook to RST format (including the expanded content of any output cells as parse literals (possibly excluding images if that's too hard))?

I Googled for this and searched SO but didn't find anything that addressed it; and I don't see any alternate file formats for saving output from the notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the IPython 1.0 you can use the `nbconvert` command:

```
ipython nbconvert --to rst your.ipynb
```

It will convert all the cels and outputs to `rst`. Images will be placed in a separate folder and included in the document using the standard rst `.. image::` syntax.

Comment: And the `download as...[rst]` will probably be added in 2.0 or later (coming in winter)